# multiplication of non integer and integer in a list

Tags: python, jython

Write a program to keep track of how much profit you make. You make $0.25 on each apple, $0.50 on each orange, $0.75 on each banana, and $0.35 on each strawberry. Return an integer representing the profit of fruits.

This is what I did and I received the error was: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

```
def sellFruits(fruits):
  fruitL = []
  a = [0] * .25
  o = [1] * .50
  b = [2] * .75
  s = [3] * .35
  totalFruitProfit = a + o + b + s
  return totalFruitProfit
```

Test case:

```
fruits = [1, 1, 1, 1]
profit = sellFruits(fruits)
print profit
1.85
```

Comment: What does `fruitL` do?

Comment: I thought I had to create a list to index from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
def sellFruits(fruits):
  a = fruits[0] * .25
  o = fruits[1] * .50
  b = fruits[2] * .75
  s = fruits[3] * .35
  totalFruitProfit = a + o + b + s
  return totalFruitProfit
```

There were several things you were doing that didn't really make sense:

- You weren't using the `fruits` parameter anywhere
- You were creating `fruitL = []` and then doing nothing with it
- `[0] * .25` is creating a list, with one item (an integer 0), and trying to multiply that sequence<sup>1</sup> by .25.  If you were trying to index some list, it wasn't happening.

So I added `fruits` before each set of brackets. This way, you're accessing the `0`th, `1`st, etc. item of the `fruits` list being passed to `sellFruits`.

Note the difference in what I changed:

- `[0]` creates a list, with one item, `0`.
- `fruits[0]` accesses the first item in list (or any sequence, tuple, ...) `fruits`.

---

1 - Multiplying a sequence by an integer duplicates the sequence that many times. `[0] * 4`, for example, yields `[0,0,0,0]`.

Comment: Also note that `[0] * 4`, for example, yields `[0,0,0,0]`.

Comment: @Tangmeister Thanks. I didn't bother mentioning that because the OP was obviously confused enough the way it is. But since I mentioned "multiply that sequence", I figured I should probably explain it. Edited.

Comment: you could write it as: `total_profit = sum(amount*profit for amount, profit in zip(fruits, [.25, .5, .75, .35]))` to get profit of fruits as a float.

Comment: @sebastian What does that accomplish that my answer does not? Mine returns a float as well.

Comment: the question asks to return an integer so I've mentioned that the code produces a float. Your answer is fine (it is appropriate given that OP is a complete beginner).

Answer (score 0):

A short code for doing this:
1.

```
def sellFruits(fruits):
        totalFruitProfit = fruits[0]*0.25 + fruits[0]*0.50 + fruits[0]*0.75 + fruits[0]*0.35
        return totalFruitProfit

fruits = [1, 1, 1, 1]
profit = sellFruits(fruits)
print (profit)
```

2.

```
fruits = [1, 1, 1, 1]
profits = [0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.35]
totalFruitProfit = 0
for i, j in zip(fruits, profits):
    totalFruitProfit += i*j
print(totalFruitProfit)
```